# WPF Bold Font - Use a different font or set Font weight?

Tags: wpf, fonts, typeface, glyph

How do I know when I should be appending "Bold" to the name of the font vs setting the font weight?
I have the following test function to demonstrate the issue:

```
public static bool IsBoldFont(string fontName, System.Windows.FontWeight fontWeight)
{
    var typeface = new System.Windows.Media.Typeface(new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily(fontName), System.Windows.FontStyles.Normal, fontWeight, System.Windows.FontStretches.Normal);
    typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out System.Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface);
    return glyphTypeface.Weight == System.Windows.FontWeights.Bold;
}
```

And these are the results:

```
IsBoldFont("Arial Narrow", System.Windows.FontWeights.Bold); // false
IsBoldFont("Arial Narrow Bold", System.Windows.FontWeights.Regular); // true
IsBoldFont("Arial", System.Windows.FontWeights.Bold); // true
```

-- Update --

I think I simplified my question a bit too much. I am converting from one software package to another. The font specified is "Arial Narrow" and Bold weight (like in MS Word - select the font, then apply the Bold Weight to it, the Font "Arial Narrow Bold" does not exist in the list of fonts).

When converting the text to draw on the canvas, the font is not drawing Bold when I am asking for ("Arial Narrow", System.Windows.FontWeights.Bold), however it is correct when changing the font family name to ("Arial Narrow Bold", System.Windows.FontWeights.Regular). How am I supposed to know to append " Bold" to the end of the family name?

Comment: Every font supports font weights like bold. or styles like italic. "Arial Narrow Bold" is a font of the "Arial Narrow" family set, that has a bold typeface by default. A group of fonts is called a font family. The font family "Arial Narrow" comprises e.g,, "Arial Narrow", "Arial Narrow Bold", "Arial Narrow Bold Italic" and "Arial Narrow Italic". To change the style or weight of a font's typeface you can always choose between setting FontWeight and FontStyle or selecting a specialized font of the same family. You decide. The effect is the same.

Comment: You only have to take into account that the relevant family members must be installed on the target machine. Thus using the base font or regular font and then adjust the typeface by changing its weight or style can be more robust.

Comment: @BionicCode  "Every font supports font weights like bold" - This does not seem to be the case for Arial Narrow. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3672803/9760608). I have updated my question for a bit more clarity.

Comment: Also another link to show the same issue in a different way [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60279978)

Comment: "Every font supports font weights like bold. or styles like italic."
That's not correct. Many font families do not have a bold or don't have an italic. Some software might simulate bold or italic if you request that, however.